# Order of Constructor/Destructor Calls When Using Inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am trying to understand the order in which constructors and destructors are called by writing some sample code and trying to follow the flow of the program. In most cases, I was able to understand (with the help of Google where needed). However, in one particular case, I have hit a bit of road-block.

This is the program I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
class baseC
{

public:
        baseC() { std::cout << "Calling constructor of base class: " << std::endl; }
        virtual char const * getName(){ return "Base Class";}
        ~baseC(){ std::cout << "Calling destructor of base class: " << std::endl;}
};

class childC : public baseC
{
public:
        childC() { std::cout << "Calling constructor of child class: " << std::endl; }
        char const * getName(){ return "Child Class";}
        ~childC(){ std::cout << "Calling destructor of child class: " << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
        baseC c3 = childC();
        std::cout << c3.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
$ g++ test_vd_se.cpp -o test; ./test
Calling constructor of base class: 
Calling constructor of child class: 
Calling destructor of child class: 
Calling destructor of base class: 
Base Class
Calling destructor of base class:
```

The compiler seems to first create a base class and the child class (this is expected), however it goes on to destroy both classes, and yet it can call a member function from the base class and goes on to destroy the base class once again.

I would be grateful if someone could explain why the functions are called in that order.

Comment: Don't forget to declare base class destructors as virtual. Otherwise deleting through a base pointer will not call derived destructors.

Comment: The most curious thing here is that we did not observe *twice* the sentence `Calling constructor of base class: `. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is you are slicing the object.

```
baseC c3 = childC();
```

Is going to create a temporary `childC` and then copy that objects into `c3`.  This is why you see

```
Calling constructor of base class:  // create base part of temporary
Calling constructor of child class: // create temporary

// the copy happens here but you do not output when copying

Calling destructor of child class:  // destroy base part of temporary
Calling destructor of base class:   // destroy temporary
```

The corret way to do this is to use a smart pointer.  If you change `main()` to

```
int main()
{
        auto c3 = std::make_unique<childC>();
        std::cout << c3->getName() << std::endl;
}
```

Or if you do not have access to smart pointers:

```
int main()
{
        baseC* c3 = new childC();
        std::cout << c3->getName() << std::endl;
        delete c3;
}
```

You get:

```
Calling constructor of base class: 
Calling constructor of child class: 
Child Class
Calling destructor of child class: 
Calling destructor of base class:
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbd5c360b0e7a0c0)</kbd>

We also need to make `~baseC()` `virtual` so the the correct destructor is called.

```
virtual ~baseC(){ std::cout << "Calling destructor of base class: " << std::endl;}
```

You will also note that now `Child Class` is printed instead of `Base Class` since now that we have a pointer dynamic dispatch kicks in and it calls the correct virtual function.

Comment: Do not forget to delete object after use, if you adding dynamic memory management to original code..

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Was adding that.  Thanks.

Comment: thank you!
With the replies above, I can better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The "anomaly" comes from the following assignment:

```
baseC c3 = childC();
```

where you first create a temporary `childC`, invoking in order the constructors from the top down:

```
Calling constructor of base class: 
Calling constructor of child class:
```

Then the assignment takes place, so a `baseC` object is created. **But this time, it is not your constructor that is invoked, but the *default copy constructor*.** That is why, we did not observe *again* `Calling constructor of base class:` (for the construction of the object `c3`). To prove it, try to add a copy-constructor to your baseC class:

```
  baseC(const baseC& other) { std::cout << "Calling Copy-constructor of base class: " << std::endl; }
```

And with the same main function, you will observe the sentence twice in the output:

```
Calling constructor of base class: 
Calling constructor of child class:
**Calling copy-constructor of base class:**
Calling destructor of child class: 
Calling destructor of base class: 
Base Class
Calling destructor of base class:
```

Finally, the temporary child object is destroyed, so the destructors are invoked from the bottom up.

```
Calling destructor of child class: 
Calling destructor of base class:
```

Now the `baseC` object `c3` is still there, invoked the getName() method, which outputs:

```
Child Class
```

And then when the variable `c3` goes out of scope (end of `main()`), `c3` is destroyed:

```
Calling destructor of base class:
```

Finally, things would be different with `baseC& c3 = ChildC();` (compiles with VS2015, I am not sure if it complies to the C++14 standard) which does not create two objects but only one. The sequence would be then:

```
contruction of baseC
contruction of childC
destruction of childC
destruction of baseC
```

Finally, it is always safer and good practice to declare your destructors as virtual.

Comment: Your solution is not going to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67884429595bf87d

Comment: @NathanOliver it compiles perfectly with VS2015 ;)

Comment: That is vecause VS215 has a non standard extension that allows non `const` references.  It is the only compiler that supports this AFAIK

Comment: That is possible. But anyway the OP is interested in the explanation of the sequence tht happened in the original code, which is true, especially the fact that the constructor of baseC does not appear twice. This was, to me, **the most curious thing in their output** :)

Comment: Be that as it may your solution only works with one compiler vendor.  Don't you think your solution should work any standard compliant compiler?

Comment: The relevant part is, as OP said: *"I would be grateful if someone could explain why the functions are called in that order."* It was not about requesting a "solution" for a specific problem, but an explanation. I will add a note about the compiler specific part.

Comment: @A.S.H: Thank you for your reply. The order of the function calls was confusing me, and it is much clearer now.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you for pointing out the subtlety regarding compilers. I will keep it in mind when writing code.